# show num_rows and fetch assoc in prepared statment

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

i tried this query many many times. but, it's still error. i'm confused . please help it :

```html
<?php
$sql = $db->prepare("SELECT nm_bahan FROM bahan WHERE nm_bahan=? ");
        $sql->bind_param("s", $_POST['nm_bahan']);
        $sql->execute();
        $sql->store_result();
        $jml = $sql->num_rows;
        
        $result = $sql->get_result();
        $data = $result->fetch_assoc();

echo $jml . "<br>" . $data['nm_bahan'];

?>
```

Comment: *"but, it's still error"* - check for the "real" errors and tell us what they are.

Comment: <b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\permata\bahan\bahan_crud.php</b> on line <b>71</b><br />

Comment: The "fatal error" means you are not returning anything with your execute() call.  Try echoing $jml.  If $jml is 0, then the likely culprit is $_POST['nm_bahan'] returning empty.  Put some error handling in your code block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your database returns only one result set. And so **you cannot get it twice.**

```
<?php
$sql = $db->prepare("SELECT nm_bahan FROM bahan WHERE nm_bahan=? ");
$sql->bind_param("s", $_POST['nm_bahan']);
$sql->execute();
$result = $sql->get_result();
$data = $result->fetch_assoc();
// I have no idea why you need this useless number but meh
$jml = $result->num_rows;

echo $data['nm_bahan'];
```